# Integration of $\Big(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\Big)^\frac{1}{6}$ using a dog bone contour

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I came across the following (part) solution to a problem which involved integration around a 'dog bone' contour. I am having trouble understanding why the limits underlined in red are used, since there is no image of the contours to accompany the solution, making it difficult to visualize what $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ represent. The upper limit $1 + \epsilon$ seems an especially odd choice. [image]

Comment: $1-\epsilon$ or $\epsilon - 1$? There is a branch point at $-1$ so I thought it might be $\epsilon - 1$.

Comment: ye it should be $\varepsilon-1$, sorry